# Create virtual 'shredder' printer

Tags: c#, vb.net, shred, virtual-printer

I need to create a virtual printer that 'shreds'

Basically here is my problem.  I have a software program that needs to 'print' a file before it will save it.  I want to be able to print to my shredder so that it saves the document, but I don't actually want the document printed.  So I need to print to a program that securely deletes the document and shows as a driver in Windows.

How would I go about doing this in C# of VB.Net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to write code for this just print to `nul`.  This has worked since DOS.  Just create a new printer, printing to a local port, and put `nul` in there for the port name.

http://www.markmmanning.com/blog/2009/01/creating-fake-printer-devnull-for.html

Comment: Is there an easy way to create a vbScript for that?

Comment: http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/installation2/how-can-i-add-a-printer-from-the-command-line-